# Printing int[] array from a display method

Tags: java

I am trying to print an int[] array from a seperate method in the same class.

```
public class LargeInteger {

    public LargeInteger(String s) {

        int[] intArray = new int[s.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            intArray[i] = Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 10);
        }
    }

    public Object display() {

         for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {     
                System.out.print(intArray[i]);
            }
    }   
}
```

My intArray is clearly being hidden from the display method, but I am not sure what to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give you the answer but you should first invest some time to look up your problem on google. Google knows "almost" everything...

```
public class LargeInteger {

    private int[] intArray;

    public LargeInteger(String s) {

        intArray = new int[s.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            intArray[i] = Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 10);
        }
    }

    public void display() {

         for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {     
                System.out.print(intArray[i]);
            }
    }   
}
```

And your *display* method should be void if it isn't returning anything..

Comment: Thanks, I tried googling of course. It is very hard to find specifics like this though. I mean I can easily find how to loop an array for instance but finding out how to split the display into another method is harder to find.

Answer (score 0):

`intArray` is a *local variable* in the constructor.
It doesn't exist anywhere else.

You need to make a private field instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the array outside of `LargeInteger` method, eg

```
private int[] intArray;

public LargeInteger(String s){

    this.intArray = new int[s.length()];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class LargeInteger {

private int[] intArray;

public LargeInteger(String s) {

    this.intArray = new int[s.length()];

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        intArray[i] = Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 10);
    }
}

public Object display() {

     for (int i = 0; i < this.intArray.length; i++) {     
            System.out.print(intArray[i]);
        }
}   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `intArray` a member of the `LargeInteger` class instead of a local to the constructor:

```
public class LargeInteger {

    private int[] intArray;

    public LargeInteger(String s) {

        intArray = new int[s.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            intArray[i] = Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 10);
        }
    }

    public Object display() {

         for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {     
                System.out.print(intArray[i]);
            }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just declare `int[] intArray` out of the constructor.

It should be

```
public class LargeInteger {

    private int[] intArray;

    public LargeInteger(String s) {

        intArray = new int[s.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            intArray[i] = Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 10);
        }
    }

    public Object display() {

         for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {     
                System.out.print(intArray[i]);
            }
    }   
}
```